# If statement improve version

Tags: php, laravel

is any Way to Improve these line of Code.i Means shortend way to write the Code?
I'm working on Laravel 8..

```
if ($request->logo) {
       $setting->updateOrCreate(['key' => 'logo'], ['value' => $request->logo]);
   }
    
if ($request->footerLogo) {
       $setting->updateOrCreate(['key' => 'footerLogo'], ['value' => $request->footerLogo]);
}
if ($request->favicon) {
    $setting->updateOrCreate(['key' => 'favicon'], ['value' => $request->favicon]);
 }
```

Comment: Don't you have an `id`/primary key column to pass as first argument?

Comment: it's settings table saving as key value ... no need for primary key for update....

Comment: That'd make it easier though :D What about sending `key` and `value` as `key` and `value` to the server?

Comment: are you trying to check if all those request inputs exists or if it they have a truthy value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do somethink like this. Keep key in array. Then inside loop check for request has key. If it has key then update row

```
  $settingKey=["logo","footerLogo","favicon"];

    foreach ($settingKey as $key){
        if($request->has($key)){
            $setting->updateOrCreate(['key' =>$key], ['value' => $request->{$key}]);
        }
    }
```

Also you can do like this for setting keys instead of hardcoding. But note if its new key then it might not be present in the db table.

```
$settingKey=Setting::pluck('key')->toArray();
```

Inspired By @N69S answer

```
$upserts = [];
    foreach ($settingKey as $key){
        if($request->has($key)){
            $upserts[]= ['key' => $key, 'value' => $request->{$key}];

        }
    }

    if(count($upserts)){
        $setting->upsert($upserts, ['key'], ['value']);
    }
```

Comment: `$settingKey=Setting::pluck('key')->toArray();` is not advised since he uses update**OrCreate**, so some keys might not be present

Comment: @N69S.thanks for mentioning. I haven't noticed actually

Answer (score 3):

You can make the upserts in only one Query ([Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts)).

This is a performance optimisation.

```
$upserts = [];
if ($request->logo) {
    $upserts[] = ['key' => 'logo', 'value' => $request->logo];
}
if ($request->footerLogo) {
    $upserts[] = ['key' => 'footerLogo', 'value' => $request->footerLogo];
}
if ($request->favicon) {
    $upserts[] = ['key' => 'favicon', 'value' => $request->favicon];
}

if ($upserts) {
    $setting->upsert($upserts, ['key'], ['value']);
}
```

Comment: Even though it's not significantly shorter, +1 for the use of `upsert` since it doesn't need an extra query to check for the record's existance. https://atymic.dev/tips/laravel-8-upserts/

Comment: @N69S good one.

Answer (score -1):

Change your request to `/route/to/update/?key=logo&value=logo-value` so you can just do the following:

```
$setting->updateOrCreate(['key' => $request->key], ['value' => $request->value]);
```

Or even better since it doesn't need an extra query to check for the record's existance as posted by @N69S. atymic.dev/tips/laravel-8-upserts

```
$setting->upsert(['key' => $request->key], ['value' => $request->value]);
```

If you want to update multiple values at once, you could post a json:

```
foreach($request->json('settings') as $key => $value) {
    $setting->updateOrCreate(['key' => $key], ['value' => $value]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: I'm not sure if you can do this with ternary operators but I think it will work

```
$query = ($request->logo) ? $setting->updateOrCreate([
            'key' => 'logo',
            'value' => $request->logo
        ]) : (($request->footerLogo) ? $setting->updateOrCreate([
            'key' => 'footerLogo',
            'value' => $request->footerLogo
        ]) : $setting->updateOrCreate(['key' => 'favicon', 'value' => $request->favicon]));
```

Comment: That's not an improvement

Comment: Shortened way to write the code as OP requested

Comment: This is not only two lines less, it's also less readable.

Comment: Let alone that the OP didn't have an else case

Comment: Please don't do this... Readability over brevity is the better choice any day..